# What is the difference between JSP and PHP regarding hosting?

Tags: php, jsp, comparison, web-hosting

Is it easy to host a jsp website like PHP? Is the server open source like Apache? and What is the best server for jsp?

Answer (score 3):

PHP is generally more of an accessible language to beginners or casual web programmers than JSP. Therefore hosting tends to be much more common and also, therefore cheaper.

JSPs are a special type of Java servlet. These run in a servlet container. In a paid for hosting environment this will typically be [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/). This is open source. I'd expect any decent Tomcat hosting company to have a setup where deployment is no more difficult than PHP. If you want to look into basic JSP hosting look for shared (rather than private) Tomcat instance options.

Comment: If you're going to a shared environment, you will also want to see what DB access tools are available. If the hosting provider has both JSP and PHP installed you'll most likely have pgAdmin or phpMyAdmin to manage postgres or mysql db's (assuming you want one of these or a db at all...)

Answer (score 1):

for first shot - memory, i think php will be extremely happy with 64MB, JSP starts with 40MB up to gigabytes depending on chosen technologies

Comment: what is the reason PHP takes less memory than JSP?

Comment: minimal installation of jsp would require apache + tomcat which will be tomcat more then apache for php (unless you compile it by your self). not mentioning glasfish which requires 512MB memory and up.

Comment: if you consider that match then you can also consider Ruby on Rails on Ruby and Django on Python

Comment: So Python is better at memory handling?

Comment: Python, Ruby and PHP will have similar memory usage (maybe not exact but probably not more them 50MB difference). If you are considering any technology now, you should think of few things like how does it fits to you, and how easy somebody else can be introduced.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, PHP limits memory to 8MB by default...